# Specifying dependable layer names in QGIS Processing Modeller

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I am creating a model in QGIS (3.10.3) Processing Modeller (Win 10[64]).

**Final Objective**

To create Voronoi polygons from centroids that are clipped to a higher, polygon, geometry.

**Hurdle**

The Voronoi clip produces slivers that either do (Voronoi-with-centroid) or do not ('merger-candidates') contain an centroid.

**Chosen method to get over the hurdle**

I create a UUID for every Voronoi (whether it has a centroid or not). Then identify the neighbours, and the shared boundary lengths as per:
https://spatialthoughts.com/2020/04/08/calculating-shared-border-lengths/. Then dissolve the merger-candidates into the neighbouring Voronoi-with-centroid with which it shares the longest boundary.

I am happy with the logic of this method and am confident it will produce the result I want.

**Issue**

However, my model (see GoogleDrive link below) is doing something odd.
The command `create UUID` does what it should, but additionally, adds a `UUID` *to the layer name*.

So, for the next instruction - 'Identify Neighbours' - when I enter the Expression dialog, QGIS offers all the `'..._OUTPUT'` from the previously completed instructions. But `Create_UUID_OUTPUT` doesn't appear to be the right thing to include in the "spatialthoughts" code linked to above.

My adaptation of that code is, so far:

```
array_to_string(array_remove_all(aggregate(    
  layer:=  **## THIS IS WHAT DOESN'T WORK YET ##**,    
  aggregate:='array_agg',    
  expression:=$UUID,    
  filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))    
),"UUID"))
```

If I double-click `Create_UUID_OUTPUT` on the top right box in Processing Modeller, `@Create_UUID_OUTPUT` appears in the code window on the left. When this is added into l`ayer:=` this then generates:
'''
"Eval Error:Cannot find layer with name or ID '' "
'''

So I looked at the "Map Layers" drop down on the lower right.

Sure enough, there is a `Voronois_fixed_with_UUIDs` layer, which is exactly what I would have expected, so, I thought, 'let's use that'.

However, when I double-click that, this generates  `Calculated_11a2a0f5_618c_4b85_90e9_07c97cdf360b` on the left.

So, the layer name itself has gained a `UUID`, and this changes every time I run the model.
I do not want that. I expect `Voronois_fixed_with_UUIDs` to be the layer name, for this not to change, and for it to appear, as is, in the code on the left when double-clicked on the right.

In QGIS desktop, the layer does appear with that name. Its properties may be seen at the bottom of this post.

So I have two questions:

1. How do I stop the `Create_UUID` instruction adding a `UUID` to the layer name?
2. What should I put in the line `layer:=  ## THIS IS WHAT DOESN'T WORK YET ##,`?

The QGIS model may be downloaded from my GoogleDrive:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CDJ_pd2alE8viwiPVH-qB70xwGfDozcC/view?usp=sharing

Layer properties in QGIS
(note, there's a UUID, but it's different - due to having run the model again):

```
Name:    
Voronois_fixed_with_UUIDs

**Source:    
MultiPolygon?crs=EPSG:27700&field=fid:long(0,0)&field=OBJECTID:long(0,0)&field=zone_code:string(14,0)&field=Shape_Length_1:double(0,0)&field=Shape_Area_1:double(0,0)&field=Shape_Length_12:double(0,0)&field=Shape_Area_12:double(0,0)&field=Shape_Length_12_13:double(0,0)&field=Shape_Area_12_13:double(0,0)&field=Shape_Length_12_13_14:double(0,0)&field=Shape_Area_12_13_14:double(0,0)&field=opcs_code:string(9,0)&field=Ward71Code:string(16,0)&field=Dist71Code:string(16,0)&field=Cnty71Code:string(16,0)&field=Pop71:double(0,0)&field=ORIG_FID:integer(0,0)&field=%24UUID:string(38,0)&uid={**f53eb83b-8da7-4f8f-a045-98a48f752bc6**}

Storage:  
Memory storage

Comment:

Encoding:
UTF-8

Geometry: 
Polygon (MultiPolygon)

CRS:
EPSG:27700 - OSGB 1936 / British National Grid - Projected

Extent: 
446240.0011192215606570,92182.7952580302953720 : 453679.9979932568967342,96610.0049105565994978

Unit:
meters

Feature count: 
41
```