# Identifying which shared boundary is longest using QGIS

Tags: qgis, boundaries, boundary-length

This is an evolution from [How to specify dependable layer names in QGIS Processing Modeller](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/381204/how-to-specify-dependable-layer-names-in-qgis-processing-modeller) but should be considered completely separately.

I am creating a model in QGIS (3.10.3) Processing Modeller (Win 10[64]).

**Final Objective**

To create Voronoi polygons from Enumeration District (ED) centroids that are clipped to a higher, polygon, geometry.

**Hurdle**

The clipped Voronoi geography contains instances that either do (Voronoi-with-centroid) or do not ('merger-candidates') contain an ED centroid.

**Chosen method to get over the hurdle**

I create a unique FragmentID for every ED Voronoi instance (whether it has a centroid or not).

Then identify the neighbours of every ED Voronoi instance, and the shared boundary lengths as per:
https://spatialthoughts.com/2020/04/08/calculating-shared-border-lengths/ (by SpatialThoughts' Ujaval).

I now have a line (MultiLineString) dataset.

The next steps are (for each 'merger candidate') to identify their neighbouring 'Voronoi-with-centroid' with which it shares the longest boundary - and is in a different district.

The fields of interest are:

1: ZONECODE **e411100***05001*  - the code of the ED Voronoi of which the 'merger candidate' fragment was a part (before clipping).

2: FragmentID **e411100***05001*_67  - the code of the 'merger candidate' (after clipping).

3: NEIGHBOURS **e411101***09003*_8,**e41110***005003*_14,**e411100***05001*_15,**e411101***09003*_14,**e411100***05003*_66,**e41110***108001*_68,**e411101***10002*_71
The codes of the Voronois ED fragments with which this ED 'merger candidate' fragment is a neighbour.

4: LENGTHS
,,2340,148,83,2289,381
The lengths of those boundaries

The **BOLD** parts of the CODES are the higher-level geography, the districts, to which the EDs belong. The **Italic** parts of the code are the EDs.

So, how would I identify that in this case, the neighbour with which **e411100***05001*_67 shares the longest boundary, and with which it should be merged, is **e411100***08001*_68 (2,289m)?

Yellow area **e411100***05001*_67 need to be allocated to **e411100***08001*_68

[image: e41110005001_67 goes to e41110008001_68]

Comment: Thanks Bera. I would prefer it to be in Model Designer if possible. I already have model and processing toolbox driven parts. Would prefer not to have a third environment.